# Czech Republic registration requirements for UK citizens

Tags: schengen, uk-citizens, czech-republic

I am planning to visit the Czech Republic later this year. Vacation, staying with friends and leaving CZ within 7 days of arriving. I am a UK citizen, with a passport that satisfies the entry requirements (issued less than 10 years ago, will have more than 3 months left before expiring etc.)

Both UK and Czech government websites make it sound like I need to register within 3 days of arrival, since the UK is no longer in the EU:
https://www.policie.cz/clanek/reporting-of-the-place-of-aliens-residence.aspx
https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/czech-republic/entry-requirements

Is this really the case? (I'll be staying at a private residence, not a hotel, which I have read would take care of this for me.)

If it is the case, where can I register in Prague, and how long should I allow for this process? Not my final destination in CZ, but I'll be flying in there and getting it out of the way before leaving Prague seems simplest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this really the case?

Yes, when you are staying somewhere where the registration is not done for you by the accommodation (i.e. private residence)

- for EU citizens: 30 days
- for others: 3 days

A list of the *Foreign Police Departments* can be found here:

- [Department of residence agendas - Police of the Czech Republic](https://www.policie.cz/clanek/oddeleni-pobytovych-agend.aspx)

  - [registration form (PDF)](http://www.policie.cz/soubor/2-prihl-listek-final-jeden-pdf.aspx)

> If it is the case, where can I register in Prague,

- [Prague - Foreign Police Department](https://www.policie.cz/clanek/odbor-cizinecke-policie-540818.aspx)

> Olšanská 2176/2
> 130 51 Prague 3
>
> - tel.:974 889 102
> - [Position Google Maps, Zoom 14](https://www.google.com/maps?ll=50.0830806,14.4643936&q=50.0830806,14.4643936&hl=en&t=k&z=14)

For the opening hours, see original page.

> and how long should I allow for this process?

No idea.

Filling out, the very simple, registration form beforehand may speed up the process.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer, and sorry for the delay in accepting it!